# Getting a delegate from an interface method

Tags: c#, interface, delegates

I have some code which basically grabs an event Handler which handles multiple events each handle method on  IHandles handles 1 event.

```
public interface IHandles { } 

public interface IHandles<T> : IHandles
{
    void Handle(T message);
}


public void SubscribeHandler(IHandles eventHandler)
{
    var genericHandler = typeof(IHandles<>);
    var supportedEventTypes = eventHandler.GetType()
            .GetInterfaces()
            .Where(iface => iface.IsGenericType && iface.GetGenericTypeDefinition() ==                   genericHandler)
            .Select(iface => iface.GetGenericArguments()[0])
            .ToList();
    // Register this handler for each of the handled types.
    foreach (var eventType in supportedEventTypes)
    {
        Subscribe(eventType.GetType(), 
                   Delegate.CreateDelegate(eventType, eventHandler, "Handle")
                  ); 
    }
}
```

Now the first bit works but im not sure whether the Create Delegate part will work and if its the best way. Is it possible to create an Action ?

It may be better to get Subscribe to store IHandles instead of Delgate , but its nice to be able to just register disposable actions especially for unit testing.

```
public IDisposable Subscribe(Type t, Delegate delegate1)
{
    var key = t;

    if (!actions.ContainsKey(key))
         actions.Add(key, new List<Delegate>());

    actions[key].Add(delegate1);

    return new DomainEventRegistrationRemover(delegate { actions[key].Remove(delegate1); });

}
```

Comment: I'm sure you didn't mean `t.GetType().GetHashCode()`. `t` is already of type `Type` and therefore your key is always 37489757. Just use `t` as the key.

Comment: ty was wondering about that and fixed  but thats not the question :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway i went with  implementing the store as IDictionary   and then create an IHandles from the Action ..